# Does VSMAX invest in smaller companies than FSEVX?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund, market-indexes

Does [VSMAX](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=VSMAX+Profile) invest in smaller companies than [FSEVX](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=FSEVX+Profile)?

> VSMAX seeks to track the performance of a benchmark index that measures the investment return of small-capitalization stocks. The fund employs an indexing investment approach designed to track the performance of the [CRSP U.S. Small Cap Index](http://www.crsp.com/products/investment-products/crsp-us-small-cap-index), a broadly diversified index of stocks of small U.S. companies.
>
> FSEVX seeks to provide investment results that correspond to the total return of stocks of mid- to small-capitalization United States companies. The fund normally invests at least 80% of assets in common stocks included in the [Dow Jones U.S. Completion Total Stock Market IndexSM](http://www.djindexes.com/totalstockmarket/), which represents the performance of stocks of mid- to small-capitalization U.S. companies.

If you look at a [chart](https://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=maximized&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1416574502466&chddm=489532&cmpto=MUTF:VSMAX&cmptdms=0&q=MUTF:FSEVX&&ei=FDZvVPH4EZGwsQeMvYGoDg), you can see that the two have a strong relationship to each other, but VSMAX performed much better over a five-year period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges: the charts show the capital appreciation *excluding* dividends. If you include dividends and calculate a total return over that period you see VSMAX up 132% vs. FSEVX up 129%, i.e. quite close. That residual difference is possibly due to a performance difference between the two benchmarks.

Comment: @JimG. Very often such charts are not adjusted for dividends. To get the actual return you either need a chart with an option to show the total return (that's how I did it with a different non-free system) or manually calculate the impact of dividends.

Comment: Aha! I actually didn't know that. One last question: Is it true that such charts do *not* factor in the fund expenses?

Comment: @JimG. I would expect expenses to be included.

Comment: You can get those funds' charts including dividends and expenses by using Vanguard's website instead of Yahoo.  It's completely free to browse.